# Clarification about div inheritance

Tags: css

I want to clarify the logic behind inheritance.

```
<div class="classics">
   <h2>Mega</h2>
     <div class="tild">
        <div class="color">
             <div class="medium">
                 <h1>Hello</h1>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

If I give `.classics` the style `display:inline-block` will that apply also apply to the `h2` element?

What about font-color?

If I give `.tild` the style`display:flex` does that mean `.color` will also inherit that value?

Comment: One thing you can do, is actually test it and see the behavior for yourself.

Comment: (1) test and see (2) read the documentation of each property to see if it's inherited or not

Comment: Though the list of heritable attributes in the other answer is worth looking over, it does not fully answer the question, or at least not in an easily digestible manner. Display is not heritable, but children of a display: flex element, though retaining their original display, will behave differently because of their parent's display value. Further, some elements can override heritability, so though font-weight is heritable, it won't be inherited by header elements like the h2 from the question.